# Division of number of days to get a year

Tags: arithmetic

Assuming a year has $360$ days and $12$ months of $30$ days each.

I can say that adding $5$ days  $2$ months and $15$ years **to** $17/10/2014 (dd/mm/yyyy)$, **is** $22$ days $12$ months and $2029$ years

Now since
$$(2014*360days)+(10*30days)+17days=725357\text{ days}$$
and
$$(15*360days)+(2*30days)+5days=5465\text{ days}$$

Then diving the number of days by $360$ to get the years why **doesn't**
$$(725357+5465)/360 =2029.ssss \text{ where s is some decimal value}$$

And instead it equals to
$$(725357+5465)/360 =2030.ssss \text{ where s is some decimal value}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $12$ months is a year, so $22$ days $12$ months $2029$ years is $22$ days $2030$ years.